# Profiling for Agda compiled programs

Tags: agda

I've developed a little program in Agda and it has some bad performance issues. One thing that I want to check is how much memory it is consuming during execution. Looking at [Agda wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), I didn't find anything about profiling support in Agda compiler. Is there a way to do it?